# How to close files that use ast.literal_eval to open them?

Tags: python, file

My program uses a lot of external files. Mostly these files only contain one dictionary. Currently I am opening the files like this:

```
userdata = ast.literal_eval(open("./users.txt", "r").read())
```

This saves the dictionary into the variable userdata. Now I can alter the the values a bit and then write the dictionary back in like this:

```
open("./users.txt", "w").write(str(userdata))
```

Obviously I can't close the files with `userdata.close` because userdata is not a file object and rather just a dictionary. How to close these files or do they selfclose?

The file can be summarized to just contain this string: `{'name' : 'User1', 'money' : 50}`
(in reality there would be multiple users and multiple keys)

Comment: Why not just call `open` before `literal_eval` so you have access to the file object? And/or wrap the call to `literal_eval` in a `with`.

Comment: Could you provide an example? Do you mean `userdata = open("./users.txt", "r") with ast.literal_eval`

Comment: No. `f = open(...); userdata = ast.literal_eval(f.read()); f.close()`, or, ideally, the way with `with` shown in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the context manager feature to open files, the `with` keyword. That ensures files are always closed when the scope of the context manager ends.

Read it using:

```
with open("./users.txt", "r") as f:
    userdata = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

And write it using:

```
with open("./users.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(userdata))
```